# How to understand this strange looking cube root function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I started messing around in Desmos and I decided to see what it looks like when you put a cubic function inside of a cube root, and I got a truly fascinating curve. It mostly looks like a straight line but it has this fascinating "hump" in the middle. I'm having trouble understanding *why* the function looks this way though. Here is a screenshot of the Desmos page:

[image: Desmos Screenshot]

Comment: You may be interested in knowing that cubic curves in general take a variety of strange shapes. See Wikipedia's ["Cubic plane curve" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_plane_curve). Categorizing them is a bit of a challenge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take for simplicity

$$f(x) = (x^3+1)^{1/3}$$

it has the 'hump' in $[-1,0]$ , and this is true because in that interval $0<x^3+1 < 1$ so when you apply the cube root the value of $f(x)$ increases, while instead in $(-\infty,-1)$ and $(0,+\infty)$ it resembles $f(x) = x$ because more you move away from the interval $[-1,0]$  more the $+1$ in $x^3+1$ becomes less important indeed  $(x^3+1)^{1/3} \sim x $ when $x \to \pm \infty $ .